# ProgressDialog + broadcastreceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, progressdialog

Good day! Help please! How do I join `ProgressDialog` + `BroadcastReceiver`.? I load the page in a separate thread using the library jsoup. As Georgia: display `ProgressDialog`. But if you do not want to take the internet with Toast broadtsastretseiver that no internet.

Here is the code activity:

```
package com.demo;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
public class ObedActivity extends Activity {
    WebView mWebView;
    ProgressDialog mProgress;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        this.registerReceiver(this.mConnReceiver,
                new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.www);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new DemoClient());
        mWebView.setBackgroundColor(0);
        mWebView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg);
        mProgress = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Загружаю.", "Нужно подождать..."); 

        Thread downloadThread = new Thread( 
                new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
        Document doc = null;
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://google.ru").get();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Elements ele = doc.select("div#sample");
        String html = ele.toString();
        mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
            }
        }
        );

        downloadThread.start();
        }
    private BroadcastReceiver mConnReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            boolean noConnectivity = intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false);
            String reason = intent.getStringExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_REASON);
            boolean isFailover = intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_IS_FAILOVER, false);

            NetworkInfo currentNetworkInfo = (NetworkInfo) intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
            NetworkInfo otherNetworkInfo = (NetworkInfo) intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_OTHER_NETWORK_INFO);

            if(currentNetworkInfo.isConnected()){           
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    };
      private class ObedActivityClient extends WebViewClient 

      {
          @Override
          public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) 
          {
              view.loadUrl(url);
              return true;
          }
          public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
              if(mProgress.isShowing()) {
                  mProgress.dismiss();
          }
          }
      }
      @Override
      public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
      {
          if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) 
        {
              mWebView.goBack();
              return true;
          }
          return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
      }
}
```

Comment: Probably your trying to do something on the UI-thread that isnt on the UI-thread, try using runOnUIThread runnable to update the ui

Comment: And although this is tangential to the original question, it is recommended to use AsyncTask instead of Thread directly..